# Como hacer select con tablas relacionadas

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

tengo dos tablas (cliente) y (factura), para registrar una factura lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("insert into factura (identificacion, nombrecp, " + "fecha, iva, tipo, vtotal, descripcion, subtotal) " +
                                              "values ('" + idCliente.Text + "', '" + nombreCliente.Text +
                                              "', '" + fecha.Text + "', '" + IVA.Text + "', '" + tipoFactura.Text +
                                              "', '" + totalPagar.Text + "', '" + descripcion.Text +
                                              "', '" + Subtotal.Text + "')", conexion);
```

No he encontrado la forma de hacer una consulta que por el numero de factura me diga que cliente esta asociado, el valor y el producto que compro.
He buscado por internet y lo que encuentro todo lo que encuentro cada vez me enreda más. La tabla esta relacionada 1:M, ojala puedan ayudarme lo mas pronto posible!! :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo que estoy usando para la consulta es este:

```
select identificacionc, nombre
from cliente cli inner join factura fac
on fac.identificacion = fac.identificacion
where numero = 32;
```

lo mire en una pagina he intente usarlo pero no entiendo bien toda la query y no me muestra todos los datos que necesito.

Comment: sería genial si agregas cual es la lógica que se sigue para saber **si un cliente esta asociado**

Comment: no entiendo eso de la lógica, tu disculpa si la respuesta es muy obvia pero soy muy principiante en SQL server.

Comment: yo asocio las dos tablas por medio de la FK que es identificación, lo que necesito hacer es que al yo hacer el reporte de x numero de factura no solo me diga los datos de la factura sino que me diga a que cliente pertenece esa factura, no se si me estoy explicando bien.

Comment: claro que si te explicas, y se puede hacer espera; solo para cumplir con las reglas de la comunidad te pediría agregues lo que llevas intentado; aunque sea mínimo

Comment: Esta es la query que intento hacer para la consulta:

select identificacionc, nombre
from cliente cli inner join factura fac
on fac.identificacion = fac.identificacion
where numero = 32;

Comment: en la tabla facturas, que campo es la llave foránea?

Comment: identificacion.

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener lo que me mencionas en los comentarios; dado un número de **factura** obtener los datos del cliente

Usamos un **INNER JOIN**

El uso de *Inner Join* nos permite hacer un match de lo que existe en la tabla de la izquierda con la tabla de la derecha y entonces mostrarme todos los registros

**Código**

```
SELECT cliente.nombre, factura.identificacion, factura.nombrecp, factura.fecha
       factura.iva, factura.tipo, factura.vtotal, factura.descripcion, factura.subtotal
       factura.estado
FROM cliente
INNER JOIN factura ON cliente.identifcacionc = factura.identificacion
WHERE factura.numero = 32;
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

1. Al hacer un `SELECT` idealmente yo hago esto `tabla.columna`
2. Hago un `FROM` de la tabla `cliente`
3. El `INNER JOIN` lo hago con la tabla facturas
4. Uso el `ON` para indicar que el `JOIN` se lleve a cabo en `cliente.identificacionc = facturas.identificacion` por que una es la llave primaria y la otra la llave foránea que estan uniendo ambas tablas
5. Al final para que de toda la consulta anterior solo me muestre las coincidencias de un registro en específico hago uso del `WHERE` y añado que muestre todo `donde` **factura.numero = 32**

Pruebalo primero desde tu gestor de bases de datos y cualquier cosa comentamelo

Comment: Ya lo probé en el gestor y si me muestra el registro deseado, otro inconveniente que siempre he tenido es que cuando hago las query por (parámetros) nunca me ejecuta la ejecuta. Pero eso ya es caso aparte con lo que estoy preguntado en este momento. Parece que si me sirvió, muchas gracias!! (Y)

Comment: Viejo, disculpa de nuevo, para poder ver en la misma consulta que producto compró el cliente también debo relacionar la tabla producto a factura o a cliente?

Comment: siguiendo la misma lógica con el uso de **INNER JOIN** ahora deberás relacionar 3 tablas y hacer dos `INNER JOIN` ya tienes la base ahora solo te toca acompletarla; de todos modos si la intentas y no te queda ya sabes que puedes abrir una nueva pregunta y con gusto se te apoya @EdwardSc